# Inverse Modulo for use in Cryptography

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am investigating the hill cipher. The determinant of my encryption matrix is a negative number, and I need to find the inverse modulo (using mod 26) of this determinant. This is eventually used to create the deciphering matrix. Do I take the absolute value of the determinant, and hence make it positive, or is there a method to find it as a negative.

The determinant to find reciprocal modulo 26 of is -441.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: By the inverse aw in the dupe:  $-441\equiv 1\Rightarrow (-441)^{-1}\equiv 1^{-1}.\ $  Or use $\,(ab)^{-1}\equiv a^{-1}b^{-1}\,$ for $\,a\equiv -1\ \ $

Comment: I am in year 11, can you please help explain this a bit more i do not fully understand. Could you help by explaining the process of finding the inverse modulo of -441.

Comment: $-411+17\cdot26=1$ so $-441\equiv1 \bmod {26}$ and $(-441)^{-1}\equiv1^{-1} \equiv1 \bmod {26}$.